# Getting error when casting Boolean types when using LINQ to DataSets

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

Ok I seem to always solve the issue of casting Boolean types when using LINQ to DataSets, but it seems like each new resultset brings a new problem.  So take a look at the following line which is populating a Boolean property on an object using LINQ:

```
.IsActive = If(fd.IsNull("IsActive"), False, fd.Field(Of Boolean)("IsActive"))
```

I have also had *some* success with the following:

```
.IsActive = If((fd.Field(Of Integer?)("IsActive").HasValue), fd.Field(Of Integer)("IsActive"), False)
```

This time neither approach worked. The "IsActive" type in the Database is of type '**bit**' and in the DataSet, all records returned have either a '0' or '1' as their value. Regardless I am getting the following error:

*"Specified cast is not valid. When casting from a number, the value must be a number less than infinity."*

I would like to understand what I am doing incorrectly here. Can anyone explain how I *should* be casting this? Thanks!

Comment: Why is the column `IsActive` in the datatable not a boolean? How do you fill the datatable? A typed dataset generated by Visual Studio usually makes boolean datacolumns from bit fields in the database.

Comment: Actually there is no 'Boolean' type in SQL Server (2008); you use a 'bit' field for these type values. However, your comment made me do a 2nd look to the database and determined the solution listed below. I 1 upped your comment.

Comment: I know, I was referring to the dataset. So it still makes me wonder...

Comment: You probably saw my comment; it was not a boolean in the DataSet because I had the incorrect type all together in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found a solution (more like a work-around) to the original problem, and then found the origination of the problem when looking back to the database. The workaround was to cast the value to a String, and then convert to a Boolean. Really odd why I had to do this to a 'bit' field, but it worked:

```
.IsActive = If(fd.IsNull("IsActive"), False, CBool(fd.Field(Of String)("IsActive").ToString()))
```

OK that still didn't seem right, my original code in the original post *should and does* work for bit/boolean types. Well after doing a 2nd back to the database I found my oops. For whatever reason I made that column by accident a 'char(1)' field. No wonder I had to cast to a string. After making the column a 'bit' the original code worked.